# Vuejs event on change of element value?

Tags: javascript, element, vue.js

I have an element that I want to watch for a change like this:

```
<span id="slider-value-upper" class="lower">50</span>
```

Is it possible to do this cleanly with vuejs? I tried looking in the docs but I could not find anything like this.

I want to launch a custom event whenever '50' changes to something else with VueJs.

Comment: Which property do you want to change?

Comment: I just want the grab the span element's value after it has changed. This value is hooked up to a slider and I want to pass the element's value to vuejs when it is changed by a slider.

Comment: Is the slider native javascript or Jquery? Cause Vue cant detect that. Its also an advise to not use Jquery for this kind of things while using Vue, Better search for an Vue library/pachage

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Have you tried with [`watch`](http://vuejs.org/api/#watch)?
In your case it would be something like this.

**template**

```
<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
    <span id="slider-value-upper" class="lower">{{myValue}}</span><br />
    <input v-model="myValue">
</div>
```

**js code**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Watch example',
        myValue: 50
    },
    watch: {
        'myValue': function(val, oldVal){
        if (val < 50) {
            this.message= 'value too low!';
        }else{
          this.message= 'value is ok';
        }
      }
    }
})
```

check out [**the example**](https://jsfiddle.net/k7gypb21/)

Comment: This works but only when the actualy span element value is being changed by typing something else in the input field. My slider manipulates the value in the input box without typing and it doesn't trigger than.

Comment: it change only when typing because I added `v-model` to the input, you should bind the `v-model` to the input type that is changing your value. If you are changing your value without inputs, for example directly with javascript, then you must keep in sync the `data` property of your Vue component, and reactivity would do the magic. Anyway, if you want more details you should add the portion of code that actually make the change

Comment: What if the myValue is not in the root but inside an object like... first: {myValue: '' } .. since is not possible to put in the watch something like 'first,myValue'... what's the right way for it?'

Comment: @SoldierCorp you can `v-model` on a computed property that `get`s the value from `first.myValue` and `set`s the value on `first.myValue`