# vuejs events not firing when used with laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm new to vuejs i have been trying to get an onchange event in vuejs on laravel blade to work but cant seem to get it to work but outside of laravel it works fine.
here is my code

index.blade.php

```
<div id='root'>
<division divisions="{{$districts}}"></division>
</div
```

in index.js

```
Vue.component('division',{
    template:`
     <p class="control">
        <span class="select">
        <select name="district_id" class="district" @change='callme'>
          <option></option>
          <option v-for="division in mydata">{{division.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </span>
    </p>
    `,
    props:['divisions'],
    created(){

        this.mydata=JSON.parse(this.divisions);

    },
    methods:{
        callme(){

            console.log('called');
        }
    }


});


new Vue({

    el:'#root'

});
```

Comment: What is the rendered html ? Because `@` and `{{ }}` are both used as syntax by blade and vue.js.

Comment: @Amitsouko on my index.blade.php am receiving the $districts variable from controller which i pass to vue via {{$districts}} so the @ symbol i use only in my javascript not php blade and it works fine except it does not fire the change event

Comment: You could try this method using a watcher http://stackoverflow.com/a/34729027/6464691 .